# count distinct value in pandas dataframe

Tags: sql, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe with 3 columns. I am trying to find distinct and aggregated values for each group in the row.

I am using a jupyter notebook for running this. Also using python libraries like numpy

For example my original dataframe 'df' is like:

```
    Name    Subject Grade
0   Tom     Math    20
1   Tom     Sci     30
2   Tom     Eng     10
3   Tom     Math    40
4   John    Math    30
```

I want to count the number of times a student gave a particular exam and the sum of grades of both the exam.

I applied the groupby query as follows:

```
new_df = df.groupby(['Name', 'Subject']).agg({ 'Grade': np.sum, 'Subject': np.size})
```

But this resulted in only 2 columns as expected. It did demonstrate the aggregate score for each subject for each student but in the form of rows.

I also tried using crosstab:

```
pd.crosstab(df.Name,df.Subject)
```

But I am not sure how can I incorporate the aggregation function of Sum.

My expected output is as follows:

```
    Name    Eng Math    Sci GradeEng    GradeMath   GradeSci
0   John    0   30      0   0           1           0
1   Tom     10  60      30  1           2           1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its more of a pivot problem with two aggregate functions,

```
new_df = df.pivot_table(index = 'Name', columns = 'Subject', values = 'Grade', aggfunc = ['sum', 'size'], fill_value=0)\
.rename(columns = {'sum':'', 'size':'Grade'})

new_df.columns = new_df.columns.map(''.join)

new_df.reset_index(inplace = True)

    Name    Eng Math    Sci GradeEng    GradeMath   GradeSci
0   John    0   30      0   0           1           0
1   Tom     10  60      30  1           2           1
```

You can get the same result using groupby, you need to unstack the dataframe

```
df.groupby(['Name', 'Subject']).agg({ 'Grade': np.sum, 'Subject': np.size}).unstack().fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Comment: I didn't know pivot supported multiple aggfuncs until I read this answer. Nice!

Comment: @coldspeed, its super cool to know something that you didn't  ;)

Comment: @Wen-Ben, I think it was a typo

Answer (score 2):

Just modify you `crosstab`, you can achieve what you need

```
s=pd.crosstab(df.Name,df.Subject,values=df.Grade,aggfunc=['sum','count']).swaplevel(0,1,axis=1).fillna(0)
s.columns=s.columns.map(''.join)
s
      Engsum  Mathsum  Scisum  Engcount  Mathcount  Scicount
Name                                                        
John     0.0     30.0     0.0       0.0        1.0       0.0
Tom     10.0     60.0    30.0       1.0        2.0       1.0
```